# Compare REXML elements for name/attribute equality in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3, rexml

Is there a matcher for comparing REXML elements for logical equality in RSpec? I tried writing a custom matcher that converts them to formatted strings, but it fails if the attribute order is different. (As [noted in the XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags), the order of attributes should not be significant.)

I could grind through writing a custom matcher that compares the name, namespace, child nodes, attributes, etc., etc., but this seems time-consuming and error-prone, and if someone else has already done it I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried. Some sample data and what you expect the output to be, and what the actual output was instead?

Comment: I don't think it's worth showing. String comparison is a dead-end approach without first converting it to [canonical XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n2/) or something.

Comment: Also, it's not really a question of a mismatch between actual results and expectations. If I'm converting two XML elements to strings, and they differ only in the order (though not names or values) of their attributes, I pretty much know comparing the strings is going to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the [`equivalent-xml`](https://rubygems.org/gems/equivalent-xml/versions/0.6.0) gem and writing an RSpec [custom matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/custom-matchers) to convert the REXML to Nokogiri, compare with `equivalent-xml`, and pretty-print the result if needed.

The test assertion is pretty simple:

```
expect(actual).to be_xml(expected)
```

or

```
expect(actual).to be_xml(expected, path)
```

if you want to display the file path or some sort of identifier (e.g. if you're comparing a lot of documents).

The match code is a little fancier than it needs to be because it handles REXML, Nokogiri, and strings.

```
  module XMLMatchUtils
    def self.to_nokogiri(xml)
      return nil unless xml
      case xml
      when Nokogiri::XML::Element
        xml
      when Nokogiri::XML::Document
        xml.root
      when String
        to_nokogiri(Nokogiri::XML(xml, &:noblanks))
      when REXML::Element
        to_nokogiri(xml.to_s)
      else
        raise "be_xml() expected XML, got #{xml.class}"
      end
    end

    def self.to_pretty(nokogiri)
      return nil unless nokogiri
      out = StringIO.new
      save_options = Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT | Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION
      nokogiri.write_xml_to(out, encoding: 'UTF-8', indent: 2, save_with: save_options)
      out.string
    end

    def self.equivalent?(expected, actual, filename = nil)
      expected_xml = to_nokogiri(expected) || raise("expected value #{expected || 'nil'} does not appear to be XML#{" in #{filename}" if filename}")
      actual_xml = to_nokogiri(actual)

      EquivalentXml.equivalent?(expected_xml, actual_xml, element_order: false, normalize_whitespace: true)
    end

    def self.failure_message(expected, actual, filename = nil)
      expected_string = to_pretty(to_nokogiri(expected))
      actual_string = to_pretty(to_nokogiri(actual)) || actual

      # Uncomment this to dump expected/actual to file for manual diffing
      #
      # now = Time.now.to_i
      # FileUtils.mkdir('tmp') unless File.directory?('tmp')
      # File.open("tmp/#{now}-expected.xml", 'w') { |f| f.write(expected_string) }
      # File.open("tmp/#{now}-actual.xml", 'w') { |f| f.write(actual_string) }

      diff = Diffy::Diff.new(expected_string, actual_string).to_s(:text)

      "expected XML differs from actual#{" in #{filename}" if filename}:\n#{diff}"
    end

    def self.to_xml_string(actual)
      to_pretty(to_nokogiri(actual))
    end

    def self.failure_message_when_negated(actual, filename = nil)
      "expected not to get XML#{" in #{filename}" if filename}:\n\t#{to_xml_string(actual) || 'nil'}"
    end
  end
```

The actual matcher is fairly straightforward:

```
  RSpec::Matchers.define :be_xml do |expected, filename = nil|
    match do |actual|
      XMLMatchUtils.equivalent?(expected, actual, filename)
    end

    failure_message do |actual|
      XMLMatchUtils.failure_message(expected, actual, filename)
    end

    failure_message_when_negated do |actual|
      XMLMatchUtils.failure_message_when_negated(actual, filename)
    end
  end
```